# Nested structure of JSON objects/arrays : HTML select list

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having difficulty with structure of JSON objects/arrays, which i need to show into select list on my page.

```
{ 
    "DOMAINORIGIN": {
        "CIDR.DOMAIN.NAME": [
             "10.255.255.255",
             "172.31.255.255"
        ],
        "NIC.DOMAIN.NAME": [
             "192.168.255.255",
             "192.168.255.255",
             "255.255.255.128"

        ]
    }
}
```

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/smisc/api/DOMAINORIGIN.log",
      dataType: "json",
      async: true
}).done(function(data) {
  var json = JSON.stringify(data.DOMAINORIGIN); 
  alert(json);
});
```

I need to parse data from a above json object. and show the data in my select list as

```
<select name="iplist" id="iplist">
```

```
CIDR.DOMAIN.NAME   //optgroup
    10.255.255.255
    172.31.255.255
NIC.DOMAIN.NAME   // optgroup
    192.168.255.255
    192.168.255.255
    255.255.255.128
```

Identifiers in optgroup name i.e. "CIDR" , "NIC" varies each time ajax url is called but ".DOMAIN.NAME" remains constant.
Not getting idea how to put this JSON data into the select box. Please guide how to do it?

Update: (Thanks Rk003)

```
var listArray = Object.keys(data["DOMAINORIGIN"]);
//alert(listArray);
var cidr_array = data.DOMAINORIGIN[listArray[0]];
var nic_array = data.DOMAINORIGIN[listArray[1]];

$("body").append('<select name="iplist" id="iplist"></select>');
$.each(data.DOMAINORIGIN, function (key,val){
    $("#iplist").append("<optgroup label='"+key+"'></optgroup>");
});
$.each(cidr_array, function(index,val){
    $("optgroup").eq(0).append("<option value='"+val+"'>"+val+"</option>");
});
$.each(nic_array, function(index,val){
    $("optgroup").eq(1).append("<option value='"+val+"'>"+val+"</option>");
});
```

Comment: Can you bit a bit more clear? is `CIDR.DOMAIN.NAME` one of the select options? Just a label above the select?

Comment: CIDR.DOMAIN.NAME is a label above the select options, likewise NIC.DOMAIN.NAME or to many If i get in my JSON

Comment: That wasn't clear in your question. It would have been clear if you had actually put the literal html output you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = { 
    "DOMAINORIGIN": {
        "CIDR.DOMAIN.NAME": [
             "10.255.255.255",
             "172.31.255.255"
        ],
        "NIC.DOMAIN.NAME": [
             "192.168.255.255",
             "192.168.255.255",
             "255.255.255.128"

        ]
    }
};

var createDropdown = function(data) {
    var selectElement = document.getElementById('iplist');
    selectElement.innerHTML = '';

    Object.keys(data["DOMAINORIGIN"]).forEach(key => {
        var optGroupElement = document.createElement('optgroup');
        optGroupElement.setAttribute('label', key);

        data["DOMAINORIGIN"][key].forEach(ip => {
            var optionElement = document.createElement('option');
            optionElement.setAttribute('value', ip);
            optionElement.innerHTML = ip;
            optGroupElement.appendChild(optionElement);
        });

        selectElement.appendChild(optGroupElement);
    });
};
```

Call the function `createDropdown(data);` where you are calling `JSON.stringify(data);`

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, this is I need but any chance how can i put this into my ... }).done(function(data) {    ...  my HTML looks like <select name="iplist" id="iplist"> . Still learning jquery for my first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to understand, but best for dynamically generated JSON:

```js
var data = { 
    "DOMAINORIGIN": {
        "CIDR.DOMAIN.NAME": [
             "10.255.255.255",
             "172.31.255.255"
        ],
        "NIC.DOMAIN.NAME": [
             "192.168.255.255",
             "192.168.255.255",
             "255.255.255.128"

        ],
        "SOME DATA": [
             "192.168...",
             "192.168...",
             "255.255..."

        ]
    }
}
$.each(data, function (key,val){
    $("body").append("<select></select>");
    let count=0;
    $.each(val, function (key2,val2){
        $("select").append("<optgroup label='"+key2+"'></optgroup>");
        $.each(val2, function (index,val3){
            $("optgroup").eq(count).append("<option value='"+val3+"'>"+val3+"</option>");
        });
    count++;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Rk003. I don't want two dropdown instead in one dropdown i want "CIDR.DOMAIN.NAME" & "NIC.DOMAIN.NAME" as label (optgroup) and their corresponding values.

Comment: Thank You Rk003 for your time ! Looks great and working as I need. BUT Identifiers in optgroup name i.e. "CIDR" , "NIC" is not fixed it could be any value like "AISC" , "QWERTY"  but ".DOMAIN.NAME" remains constant in key value. So var cidr_array = data.DOMAINORIGIN["CIDR.DOMAIN.NAME"] I need to have this array more generic to handle and make labels and append values accordingly. Sorry to be pain!

Comment: See update in my question, I managed to do that for two keys with index. Any Further thoughts you have.